# I am unable to print from Windows 7 Starter Edition, however I can print from WordPad

Tags: windows-7, drivers, printer, wordpad

I have a HP2500 Series printer and have installed the necessary drivers for Windows 7.  When I try to print from Word Starter Edition nothing happens, it doesn't even sent it to the print queue.  However, if I copy and paste the document to WordPad everything prints correctly.

Has anyone else had this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into something very similar to this just the other day -- the test page worked, and Notepad worked, but MS Office and Lotus would throw weird errors (Office said: "Windows cannot print due to a problem with the current printer setup").

I removed all the printers, including a couple duplicate entries, and a couple old printers that no longer existed.

Went the manufacturer's site ([here's HP's support page](http://welcome.hp.com/country/us/en/support.html)) and got the latest driver.  Rebooted, and used the newly downloaded driver to reinstall the printer.

After that *all* software worked like a charm.

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

With Word Starter open and viewing a document press ctrl+P, see if it will print now.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/starter-help/quick-start-print-a-document-in-word-starter-HA010385292.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA010385337